# Subtract Year of Year-Month-Day date

Tags: r, date

I am wondering how I can subtract a specific year like 1980 from a date which is in the form of, *e.g.* "0010-01-31"

I would like to calculate the age of a person at the time if the date from which the year of birth is substracted.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Comment: take a look `d <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date('0010-03-17'))
d$year <- 1983-d$year
as.Date(d)`

Comment: thanks Sebin Sunny! 
Unfortunately I have no idea how I should do it with my data frame

I have in one column of the df different dates in the form of e.g.  "0010-01-31" 
In another column I got the year if birth of the different persons (e.g. "1999")
Now I would like to calculate the age of the person on the date in its row.

Do you understand my issue?

Comment: No problem @Matze. My behavior of telling you what to do is also borderline. If you agree, let's remove our two comments so that your question does not get polluted by out-of-subject considerations.